# Retrieving and using MongoDB array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I am building a website using a Node.js server connected to a MongoDB database.

For one of the pages I intend to take an array from the Mongo database and use it to dynamically generate a display on the webpage.

I have achieved building a dynamic display using an array in another part of my website but this was using an array I generated within the JavaScript file.

What I am struggling to get my head around is how to retrieve the array from the Mongo database and then use it in the JavaScript file.

.ejs Page

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center cocktail-text">
<h2>My Cocktails: <%= user.login.username %></h2>
</div>

<div class="myCocktails">
<div>
<div class="row text-center">
  <!-- Dynamically generated elements will go here -->

  <!-- Example of element once generated:
  <div class="col-sm myCocktailBackground">
    <img src="img/Mojito.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
    <h3>Mojito</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div> -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have successfully pulled data from the Mongo database and displayed it on the .ejs page, I just don't know how to access it in the JavaScript file. I have also been using AJAX if that is the best way to do so.

Comment: If you use Express, just send the array when you render your page : `res.render('your_page', {data: your_array});` after that, you can access your array in your EJS view under the name `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

I ended up using an ajax `GET` to my node server, on my server I searched the mongo database for the correct user and returned the data associated with that username on the database. I then parsed the data in my javascript file to get the array I wanted.

JavaScript File:

```
$.ajax({

 type: 'GET',
 url: '/saveddrinks',
 dataType: "json",
 cache: false,
 contentType: "application/json",
 success: function(data) {
   if (data) {
     //Printing data to console
     console.log(data);
     //Printing array to console;
     console.log(data.drinks);
     var drinksarray = data.drinks;
     //***WORK WITH ARRAY HERE***
    }
   else {
     console.log("no data");
    }
  }
});
```

Server.js

```
app.get('/saveddrinks', function(req, res) {
 //If user is not currently logged in, redirect them to login page.
 if(!req.session.loggedin){res.redirect('/login');return;}
 //get the requested user based on their username?
 //set username of logged in user
 var uname = sess.username;
 //this query finds the first document in the array with that username.
 //Because the username value sits in the login section of the user data we 
 //use login.username
 db.collection('users').findOne({
   "login.username": uname
   }, function(err, result) {
   if (err) {res.send(err)}
   console.log(uname + ":" + result);
   //finally we just send the result to the user page as "user"
   res.send(result);
 });
});
```